# why does switch block not let the variable to be accessible after it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i was trying to print the value of **variable** *'text'* after **switch block**. However, i didnt put any **expression** to switch so it could escape the default case and print the value of text.
Now that is going to be a syntax error.
But i want the value of text to be default.
Is there any other way I can actually escape switch expression with switch statement still being there and print the value of text as default?

```
let x = "0";

switch () { //switch with no expression 
case 0:
text = "Off";
break;
case 1:
text = "On";
break;
default:
text = "No value found";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text; //line no. 13
```

Comment: add x in switch (x) {}

Comment: @raviAshara i want the switch statement to escape the default case and other cases . That is why i didnt put any expression to switch.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp check this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error.
Your switch needs to have some expression.
I mean `switch(something here)`

Because of the syntax error the script fails to execute further and hence you are not getting the output

Answer (score 2):

The Switch does not accept empty expressions you should switch a variable or it will generate an error .. but if you want to you can use this one

```
let x = "0";

switch (true) { //switch with no expression 
case 0:
text = "Off";
break;
case 1:
text = "On";
break;
default:
text = "No value found";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; //line no. 13
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `case x==0` and so on?

Comment: in case he don't want to use any expression or variables .. but he can do this as well